# Flutter local notification unable to Navigate to another route on click when mobile is locked

Tags: apple-push-notifications

Flutter local notification unable to Navigate to another route on click when mobile is locked
and sound is snot working properly, and route is fail

If mobile is lock push notification coming and route will be proper work it si possible are nor possiple